# Can't get Answer for A Records of my Domain from dig Command

Tags: domain-name-system, domain, bind, a-record, dns-zone

I've been trying to solve my DNS-BIND problem for two days, but still no luck.  I'm really a novice in DNS configuration.

This is my record file:

```
$ttl 38400
$ORIGIN example.ir.
@   IN  SOA dns1.xordad.com. any.gmail.com. (
            1387324950
            10800
            3600
            604800
            38400 )

example.ir. IN  A   192.0.2.55
www IN  A   192.0.2.55
mail    IN  A   192.0.2.55
ftp IN  A   192.0.2.55
example.ir. IN  NS  dns1.xordad.com.
example.ir. IN  NS  dns2.xordad.com.
localhost       A       127.0.0.1
dns1            IN      A       192.0.2.55
dns2           IN      A       192.0.2.55
@               IN      MX 10   mail
@               IN      A      192.0.2.55
```

Port 53 is open. intodns.com says it could not get A records for my domain and no valid SOA record came back.  I guess that's why I can't ping my own domain.

Guys, please help.  I'm really confused.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Currently the authoritative DNS servers for your domain are dns1.xordad.com and dns2.xordad.com (this matches what WHOIS says, which is a good sign).

dns1.xordad.com will return recursive queries (eg, it resolves google.com correctly) but does not know it's authoritative for cctools.ir.

Do you also run dns1.xordad.com or is that from your ISP/registrar/something? The problem here is in dns1.xordad.com, but it's not clear from your question which host you are running this BIND on...